# How to log to stdout from spark workers using python logging module?

Tags: python, logging, apache-spark, pyspark

Can I use the python logging module to log to stdout on a master spark instance from functions that are executed in rdd.map and other functions that are distributed to worker nodes?

Specifically, I am using yarn in client mode and would like to be able to collect logs from all the workers. So if any worker runs a line such as

```
  logger.log("Starting to do something...")
```

It will be printed to stdout/other loggers on the master as if it was not executing on a node. It is acceptable to have the logs print at the end of the job when the execution is complete.

Answer (score -1):

A way to do so is to use the java virtual machine logger:

```
log4jLogger = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j
LOGGER = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)
LOGGER.info(" pyspark script logger initialized")
```

Comment: will throw an error, since worker nodes cannot access variables of driver node

Comment: I guess the question was "logging module to log to stdout on a master spark instance" and I thought she/he means driver when says "master instance"

Answer (score -3):

The first reply in [this](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/using-Log4j-to-log-INFO-level-messages-on-workers-td6746.html) answers your question, it contains a coding example ([code link](https://gist.github.com/adgaudio/0191e14717af68bbba81)).